# Scala - infer type parameters

Tags: scala

Why does this code produce an error

```
def test[A](a: List[A], f: A => A) = a.map(f)

println(test(List(1,2,3), _*2))

error: missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$2) => x$2.$times(2))
```

shouldn't Scala be able to tell that A is Int?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need a second parameter list for this to work. I'm not sure how this is defined in the spec, however I have seen this before.

```
scala> def test[A](a: List[A])(f: A => A) = a.map(f)
test: [A](a: List[A])(f: (A) => A)List[A]

scala> test(List(1))(_+1)
res1: List[Int] = List(2)
```

Comment: Type inference of generic type arguments flows strictly left-to-right and only from parameter list to parameter list. There is no unification within parameter lists and there is no backwards propagation. That's defined in the spec, although I'm too tired no to look up where.

Answer (score 1):

This is the example, how to make it work in your case without changing anything.

```
scala> println(test(List(1,2,3), (i: Int) => i * 2 ))
```

Scala's type inference is limited, sometimes you should help!

Here is the article [Making the most of Scala's (extremely limited) type inference](http://pchiusano.blogspot.com/2011/05/making-most-of-scalas-extremely-limited.html)