# Scala no argument string function vs typed String parameter

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I ran across a function that looks like this:

```
def doSomethingQuestionable(config: someConfig, value: String)(default: => String) : String
```

What is interesting is the parameterless function that gets passed in as second argument group. In the code base, the method is only ever called with a config and two strings, the latter being some default value, but as a String, not a function. Within the code body of the method, default is passed on to a method that takes 3 string arguments. So the function "default" only resolves down to a string within the body of this method.

Is there any benefit, apart from a currying usage which does not happen with this method in the code base I am going through, of defining the method this way? Why not just define it with 3 string arguments in a single argument group?

What am I missing? Some compiler advantage here? Keep in mind, I am assuming that no currying will ever be done with this, since it is a large code base, and it is not currently done with this method.

Comment: Splitting arguments into 2 lists allows type inference in certain specific cases: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13868085/

Comment: `default` is a "call-by-name" parameter.  It's lazily evaluated by the function (or not at all if it isn't needed).

Comment: People like the syntax: `f(a, b) { val s = "hi" ; s }`. http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/control-abstraction.html#9.4

Answer (score 2):

The point is to have a potentially expensive default string that is only created when you need it.  You write the code as if you're creating the string to pass in, but because it's a by-name parameter ('=> String') it will actually be turned into a function that will be transparently called whenever `default` is referenced in the `doSomethingQuestionable` method.

The reason to keep it separate is in case you do want a big block of code to create that string.  If you never do and never will, it may as well be

```
def doSomethingQuestionable(config: someConfig, value: String, default: => String): String
```

If you do, however,

```
def doSomethingQuestionable(cfg, v){
  // Oh boy, something went wrong
  // First we need to check if we have a database accessible
  ...
  // (Much pain ensues)
  result
}
```

is way better than embedding the code block as one argument in a multi-argument parameter list.

Answer (score 1):

This is a parameterless function returning a `String`:

```
() => String
```

Which is not what you have. *This*,

```
=> <WHATEVER>
```

is a parameter being passed by-name instead of by-value. For example:

```
=> String // A string being passed by-name
=> () => String // A parameterless function returning string being passed by-name
```

The difference between these modes is that, on by-value, the parameter is *evaluated* and the resulting *value* is passed, whereas on by-name, the parameter is passed "as is", and evaluated each time it is used.

For example:

```
var x = 0
def printValue(y: Int) = println(s"I got $y. Repeating: $y.")
def printName(y: => Int) = println(s"I got $y. Repeating: $y.")

printValue { x += 1; x } // I got 1. Repeating: 1.
printName { x += 1; x } // I got 2. Repeating: 3.
```

Now, as to why the method splits that into a second parameter, it's just a matter of syntactic pleasantness. Take the method `foldLeft`, for example, which is similarly defined. You can write something like this:

```
(1 to 10).foldLeft(0) { (acc, x) =>
  println(s"Accumulator: $acc\tx: $x\tacc+x: ${acc+x}")
  acc+x
}
```

If `foldLeft` was defined as a single parameter list, it would look like this:

```
(1 to 10).foldLeft(0, { (acc, x) =>
  println(s"Accumulator: $acc\tx: $x\tacc+x: ${acc+x}")
  acc+x
})
```

Not much different, granted, but worse looking. I mean, you don't write this thing below, do you?

```
if (x == y, { 
  println("Same thing") 
}, { 
  println("Different thing" 
})
```