# Scala implicit generic type auto inference

Tags: scala, type-inference, implicit

I would like to build a transform method to output a specific type through a builder, but depending the case this last take an implicit position or not will modify generic type auto inference. Curious behaviour on which i would be happy to know more about.

```scala
trait Wrap[A]

trait Toto[A, W <: Wrap[A]] {

    def fail[A2, W2 <: Wrap[A2], T2 <: Toto[A2, W2]](f: W => W2)(implicit builder: Builder[A2, W2, T2]): T2
    def works[A2, W2 <: Wrap[A2], T2 <: Toto[A2, W2]](f: W => W2, builder: Builder[A2, W2, T2]): T2
}

trait Builder[A, W <: Wrap[A], T <: Toto[A, W]]


type A1
type W1 <: Wrap[A1]
type A2
type W2 <: Wrap[A2]
type T2 <: Toto[A2, W2]

val t1: Toto[A1, W1]
implicit val builder: Builder[A2, W2, T2]
val f: W1 => W2


t1.fail(f) // inferred type arguments [Nothing, W2, Nothing] do not conform to method fail's type parameter
    
t1.fail(f)(builder) // inferred type arguments [Nothing, W2, Nothing] do not conform to method fail's type parameter
/**
 * [error]  found   : Test.this.W1 => Test.this.W2
 * [error]  required: Test.this.W1 => W2
 */

 t1.works(f, builder) // compiles
```

Comment: Yes, it is intentional because i suppose they do not play a role in that case.

Comment: @jwvh https://scastie.scala-lang.org/4xqX9GgPRRK8JSfayWf7sw

Answer (score 3):

The thing is not in implicits. If you rewrite `works` with two parameter lists

```
def works1[A2, W2 <: Wrap[A2], T2 <: Toto[A2, W2]](f: W => W2)(builder: Builder[A2, W2, T2]): T2
```

this will not work either. If `f` and `builder` are in the same parameter list then in

```
t1.works(f, builder)
```

`A2, W2, T2` are inferred, but if `f` is in the first parameter list and `builder` is in the second then in

```
t1.works1(f)(builder)
//          ^
//         here
```

from the first parameter list `f` only `W2` is inferred correctly, so `A2` and `T2` are inferred to be `Nothing` and then during type-checking of the second parameter list it's too late to come back and fix inference and this fails.

[Scala type inference and multiple arguments list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42175614/scala-type-inference-and-multiple-arguments-list)

[Type inference with type aliases and multiple parameter list function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43635297/type-inference-with-type-aliases-and-multiple-parameter-list-function)

[Scala - infer type parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13868085/scala-infer-type-parameters)

So if you want to use implicit `builder` (and then you can't use single parameter list) try to rewrite your code. Try to replace type bounds with implicit constraints (this changes order of type inference) and then you'll have to replace traits with abstract classes so that they can have implicit parameters

```
trait Wrap[A]

abstract class Toto[A, W](implicit ev: W <:< Wrap[A]) { 
  def fail1[A2, W2, T2](f: W => W2)(implicit builder: Builder[A2, W2, T2], ev1: W2 <:< Wrap[A2], ev2: T2 <:< Toto[A2, W2]): T2
}

abstract class Builder[A, W, T](implicit ev: W <:< Wrap[A], ev1: T <:< Toto[A, W])

t1.fail1(f) //compiles
```